Switch between different documents in the same window
This feature comes from one book Introduction to Machine Learning.
Its notebook edition provides the following interactive features without open new window:

But it cannot view and edit the source code with CTRL+SHIFT+E.

What is the question?  You want to know how to construct such a document?  Player Pro is not Mathematica; it cannot be used to create new content and may not let you view the source.

yes, I  want to know how to construct such a document.

It's a docked cell. Find out what's in it by executing Options[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells] in the notebook.

Essentially, it’s a docked cell with buttons that close the current notebooks and open the new notebook also with the same docked cell (and same window properties) so it looks seamless.  This video has relevant information:
https://youtu.be/iUobpMR04Kw?feature=shared

@Bflat Notebooks for Eric Schulz's Tech Conf talk are available here and a link to the Wolfram-hosted video is http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?channel=88&video=776 -- I think if you included the speaker's name, presentation title, and the conference link, it would make a good answer. It's a complicated task, and I can understand why no one will want to give a full answer. I think you point to valuable resources, and it is preferred that such information reside in answers and not just in comments.

Essentially, it’s a docked cell with buttons that close the current notebooks and open the new notebook also with the same docked cell (and same window properties) so it looks seamless.
See Eric Schulz's Tech conference talk.  It's available here.  A link to the Wolfram-hosted video is available here.  It it he gives an overview on how to create this kind of textbook.
tip: Use the following window options when opening the new notebook when the button in the docked cell is clicked.  This forces the new notebook to adopt the same window options of the current one.  Then close the old one.  It looks seamless this way.
WindowSize->CurrentValue[ButtonNotebook[],WindowSize],
WindowMargins->AbsoluteCurrentValue[ButtonNotebook[],WindowMargins],
Magnification->CurrentValue[ButtonNotebook[],Magnification]


This answer will be much better and useful if you include some minimal code that can be used to create such navigation toolbar.
